# Required only working with jquery-form-validator-rails when using remote: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I've recently implemented a phone/sim checker. The first form input requires the user to input their phone number. If the phone number exists in the database, render the phone number found message, otherwise replace the phone number form with the sim number form. Again if the sim number exists in the database, render the sim number found message, otherwise render the sim number not found message.

The problem I'm currently experiencing is that I've added the gem:jquery-form-validator-rails (https://github.com/gustaflindqvist/jquery-form-validator-rails) and set it up appropriately. Followed the documentation on how to validate fields, I can get the form to show a message if nothing has been entered. However when I try to validate its min length I'm it doesn't work, it responds to a controller method instead of checking the validation.
Also the validation doesn't even work on the sim number form: app/views/phones/_sim.html.erb

Implemented Code Below:
app/models/phone.rb

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone_number, length: {minimum: 11, maximum: 11}, allow_blank: false
  validates :sim_number, length: {minimum: 12, maximum: 12}, allow_blank: false
end
```

app/controllers/phones_controller.rb

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController
  def checkphone
    @phone_number = Phone.where(phone_number: params[:phone][:phone_number])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @phone_number.exists?
        format.js {render 'phone-found'}
      elsif @phone_number.blank?
        format.js {render 'phone-not-found'}
      else
        format.js {render 'errors'}
      end
    end
  end

  def checksim
    @sim_number = Phone.where('sim_number = ?', params[:sim][:sim_number])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sim_number.exists?
        format.js {render 'sim-found'}
      elsif @sim_number.blank?
        format.js {render 'sim-not-found'}
      else
        format.js {render 'errors'}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def phone_params
    params.require(:phone).permit(
      :phone_number
    )
  end

  def sim_params
    params.require(:sim).permit(
      :sim_number
    )
  end
end
```

app/views/phones/index.html.erb

```
<div id="phone-number-found"></div>
<div id="phone-number-not-found"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<%= form_for :phone, :url => url_for(:action => 'checkphone', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, html: { id: 'phone-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Phone Number:" %>
  <%= f.number_field(:phone_number, class: "field", data: {
    :validation => "required validate_max_length length11",
    "validation-error-msg" => "This field is required, must only be numbers and be a minimum length of 11 characters"
    }) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/phone-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('Phone Number Found!');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#error').html('');
$('#phone-number-form').hide();
```

app/views/phones/phone-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').append("<%= j render(partial: 'sim') %>")
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Phone Number Not Found!');
$('#error').html('');
$('#phone-number-form').hide();
```

app/views/phones/_sim.html.erb

```
<div id="sim-number-found"></div>
<div id="sim-number-not-found"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<%= form_for :sim, :url => url_for(:action => 'checksim', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, html: { id: 'sim-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Sim Number:" %>
  <%= f.number_field(:sim_number, class: "field", data: {
    :validation => "required validate_max_length length12",
    "validation-error-msg" => "This field is required, must only be numbers and be a minimum length of 12 characters"
    }) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/sim-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('Sim Found')
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
```

app/views/phones/sim-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Sim Number Not Found!');
$('#error').html('');
```

app/views/phones/error.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#error').html('Error!');
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an MCVE and _state your question_.

Comment: My phone number form validates only if the field is empty. It doesn't validate and show the validation message if i enter more than 11 characters. The form skips this and renders phone-found.js.erb or phone-not-found.js.erb depending if the value exists in the db or not.
My question is: 

How do I get it to validate min and max lengths?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the length of your phone in the view using that plugin ? or with rails ?. If you're trying to do it with the plugin, you're missing the `maxlength` attribute in your html element, and I don't know if you're doing the `$.validate()`. In the other hand, if you're trying to validate the length on the rails side, you're doing it wrong; what you're doing right now is just checking if the phone number exists, you're never running the rails validator, those validators run when you're creating a new instance(or if you run .`valid?`) not when you're fetching an existing one.